# .sum data from query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to .sum a field from the following query:

```
  def self.busqueda_general(params)
  query = select('venta.Id,venta.TOTAL')
       .distinct
       .joins('left outer join detallevet ON venta.Documento=detallevet.Docto and venta.RutaId=detallevet.RutaId')
       .where("(venta.RutaId = :rutaId or :rutaId = '') AND (detallevet.Articulo = :articulo or :articulo = '')  AND (venta.CodCliente = :codcliente or :codcliente = '') AND (venta.IdEmpresa = :idempresa)",{rutaId: params[:search], articulo: params[:search3], codcliente: params[:search2], idempresa: params[:search6]})
  query = query.where('venta.Fecha >= ? AND venta.Fecha <= ?', (params[:search4].to_date.beginning_of_day).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %T'), (params[:search5].to_date.end_of_day).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %T')) if params[:search4].present? and params[:search5].present?
  query
   end
```

In the method of the controller I call the query and sum it as follows:

```
@monto_total = Vent.busqueda_general(params).sum(:TOTAL)
```

but the problem is that the query is showing me records that are not repeated thanks to .distinct but with the .sum is adding up all the records including the repeated ones, ignoring the .distinct

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@monto_total = Vent.busqueda_general(params).sum(:TOTAL).to_f
```

you can to use to_s (to convert in string) to_f -> float, to_i -> integer

Answer (score 0):

You have a group by clause, so you get one sum(Total) for every combination of ID/Total.

```
   .group('venta.Id,venta.TOTAL')
```

To me looks like you don't need this group by clause.

UPDATE::

```
query = where(Id: select('venta.Id')
 .joins('left outer join detallevet ON venta.Documento=detallevet.Docto and venta.RutaId=detallevet.RutaId')
 .where("(venta.RutaId = :rutaId or :rutaId = '') AND (detallevet.Articulo = :articulo or :articulo = '')  AND (venta.CodCliente = :codcliente or :codcliente = '') AND (venta.IdEmpresa = :idempresa)",{rutaId: params[:search], articulo: params[:search3], codcliente: params[:search2], idempresa: params[:search6]}))
```

Change your main `query` to this keeping everything else same. Ideal way would be to move `join` on  `detallevet` to `where` clause.

Comment: Ok I removed the .group. Now the problem is that the query is showing me records that are not repeated thanks to .distinct but with the .sum is adding up all the records including the repeated ones, ignoring the .distinct

Comment: can you update your question with new details, query and expected output

Comment: Quickest I can think of is to make your first query just select `venta_id` and make it subquery to the main query. Let me post it in UPDATE